# What is the difference between NetworkStream and Socket classes?

Tags: .net, sockets, network-programming

I have a project where I might want to abstract the communication between client and server. I was initially using Sockets and TCP. I then thought that it might be nice to be able to switch to an inter process communication channel. I then looked at System.IO.PipedStream class and saw that there was a lot of overlap between the PipeStream and the Socket class. But when I had a look at the Socket class it inherits from Object. So there is no common interface or abstract class between Socket and PipeStreams.

I then remembered something about NetworkStream. It apparently wraps a Socket class. But at least both NetworkStream and PipeStream inherit from Stream. Which means I can swap my implementation out. I think, I haven't tried this yet. I have been using sockets all this time.

So my question is: Is there any disadvantage to using the NetworkStream class over the Socket class. Any gotchas or anything to watch out for?

Comment: For high-level communication it's better to user WFC than raw TCP or Pipes

Comment: What exactly do you mean "it might be nice..."? Keep in mind that TCP/IP sockets are a perfectly valid form of inter-process communication.

Comment: @Stephen. I imagined that it would be faster than getting the TCP/IP stack involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are forced to use low level options such as sockets and pipes, and you want an abstraction for pulling streaming data from those data sources then the [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class is perfect, as it provides that abstraction for that model.

If you code against Stream instances, then you can have anything implement the Stream, and not worry about the underlying transport.

In reference to using a NetworkStream vs a Socket, a NetworkStream just wraps a Socket instance and applies the calls to the pull model (the Stream) to the Socket.

Comment: @ casperOne: Thanks for the answer. Can you expand on what you mean by pull model?

Comment: @uriDium: Updated answer to distinguish between pull and push models.

Comment: ehh. what are you talking about? What have Pull and Push to do with things?

Comment: @jgauffin: I just realized I was confusing the named pipe stream with the SerialPort class (I don't know why) which uses a push vs a pull model.  I've updated the answer to remove the distinction and keep it more on target.

Comment: @casperOne: The model is as follows. We need one thread that keeps posting to the stream and getting acks from the stream. Then another thread that keeps receiving and sending acks back. Sockets were perfect. But now we have a situation where the client and server can be on the same machine. I thought it might be even faster if they just used named pipes instead of sockets.

Comment: @uriDium: That's basically a duplex channel, where both parties can send messages to each other at any time.  You should *really* consider WPF at this point, as it supports this messaging pattern, as well as using both TCP (socket-based) and named pipe transport channels.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not know about any disadvantages when switching from `Socket` to `NetworkStream` you will most likely not need to use a Socket directly. `Socket` gives you a lot more control, but since you are not aware of the disadvantages you will most likely not need that control.

Just remember that things do not become reliable or fast just because you are switching to a `NetworkStream`. (Might be easy to forget when you start to switch between different stream implementations).