# Difference between NetworkStream.Write and StreamWriter.Write

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, streamwriter, networkstream

Hello it would be very nice if someone could tell me the difference between the NetworkStream.Write and the StreamWriter.Write. I'm using a TcpClient and don't know which should be better to use for writing to the Stream.

Comment: Here is a link to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325005/what-is-the-difference-between-networkstream-and-socket-classes

Comment: One writes raw bytes, the other writes objects (strings. numbers and so on) converting them to bytes for you.